# Required solution to an aptitude question

Tags: diophantine-equations, algebra-precalculus

The following is an [aptitude problem (question no: 29-32)](http://placement.freshersworld.com/placement-papers/IBM/Placement-Paper-Whole-Testpaper-37851), I am trying to solve:-

> Questions 29 - 32:
>
> A, B, C, D, E and F are six positive integers such that
>
> B + C + D + E = 4A
>
> C + F = 3A
>
> C + D + E = 2F
>
> F = 2D
>
> E + F = 2C + 1
>
> If A is a prime number between 12 and 20, then
>
> 1. The value of F is
>
> (A) 14
>
> (B) 16
>
> (C) 20
>
> (D) 24
>
> (E) 28
>
> 1. Which of the following must be true?
>
> (A) D is the lowest integer and D = 14
>
> (B) C is the greatest integer and C = 23
>
> (C) B is the lowest integer and B = 12
>
> (D) F is the greatest integer and F = 24
>
> (E) A is the lowest integer and A = 13

Now there are 5 equations to solve 6 variables. So I am at a loss on how should I start solving the problem? Any help from anybody is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

B + C + D + E = 4A ------1

C + F = 3A ----------------2

C + D + E = 2F -----------3

F = 2D --------------------4

E + F = 2C + 1-----------5

Also A can 13,17 or 19

Eliminating D from all the equations we get

B+2F = 4A ------6

C+F = 3A -------7

C+E = 3F/2 -----8

E+F = 2C+1 ----9

Adding 7 and 8

2C+E+F = 3(A+F/2)

4C+1 = 3(A+F/2)

Substituting value of C from 7

4(3A - F) + 1 = 3(A+F/2)

=> A = (11F - 2)/18
=> Only for A = 17, F is an integer

Therefore A = 17, F = 28, C = 23 , D = 14, B = 12, E = 19

1.) F = 28

2.) B = 12 and the lowest

Answer (score 0):

Keep substituting and work with the equations to end up having equations for the other variables in terms of  `A`, i.e. something like `B = 10A+3`. There are only certain values of `A` that are a prime number between 12 and 20. For those values of `A`, using your equation for `F`, you can compute the possible values of `F`. Once the noninteger or nonpositive values are removed there should be only one value for `F`. Likewise the second question can be answered.

Answer (score 0):

F=2D implies F must be even.
E+F=2C+1 implies E+F must be odd, hence E must be odd (as F is even).
Let E=2q+1, hence 2q+1+F=2C+1, hence 2q+2D=2C, hence C=q+D
C+D+E=2F, hence q+D+D+2q+1=2(2D), hence 3q+1=2D, hence q must be odd.
Let q=2r+1, hence 6r+4=2D, hence D=3r+2.

Summarising so far, we get:
D=3r+2
F=2D=6r+4
E=2q+1=4r+3
C=q+D=5r+3

C+F=3A, hence 5r+3+6r+4=3A, hence 11r+7=3A, hence 11(r-1)+18=3A, hence r-1 must be a multiple of 3.
Let r-1=3s, hence 11(3s+1)+7=3A, hence 33s+18=3A, hence A=11s+6.

Summarising so far, we get:
D=3r+2=9s+5
F=6r+4=18s+10
E=4r+3=12s+7
C=5r+3=15s+8
A=11s+6

Finally B+C+D+E=4A, hence B+15s+8+9s+5+12s+7=4(11s+6)

Hopefully you can finish off from here.